# Dynamically hide Laravel barryvdh debugbar

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I could not able to hide [**Laravel Debugbar**](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) dynamically, i.e on the run time. I have tried the following from parent Controller class constructor:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class Controller extends BaseController {

    use AuthorizesRequests,
        DispatchesJobs,
        ValidatesRequests;
    public $foo = 'null';

    public function __construct() {
        \Debugbar::disable();
      // and also
      config(['debugbar.enabled' => false]);
....
```

All of the above tries failed. I'd like to mention that controller is the parent controller of all other controllers' classes.

The only working way is not dynamic way, where I have to change configuration manually. I don't know why the override configurations doesn work as the [**documentation states**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#accessing-configuration-values)?

Comment: Can you add some more information about your use case. Do you want to disable the debugbar with a parameter or are you looking to have the debugbar disabled in certain environments? If not either can you elaborate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without seeing all you code, yours should work. Here is how I configure mine to work in a local environment and disable it with specific requests.

**AppServiceProvider**

```
use Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider as DebugbarServiceProvider;

...

public function register()
{
  if ($this->app->environment('local')) {
    $this->app->register(DebugbarServiceProvider::class);
  }
}
```

Where I would like to disable I put.

```
use Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade as Debugbar;

...

if (App::environment('local')) {
  Debugbar::disable();
}
```

## Update per comment

Why do you put something in your routes file like this.

```
use Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade as Debugbar;

...

Route::group(array('domain' => 'admin.example.com'), function()
{
   Debugbar::disable();
});
```

Comment: Indeed, I run the website via some virtual hosts, so, I want to check the host name and then for some hosts I need to disable the debugger.

Comment: It works but it disable debugbar for all domains not only the regarded domain in the group.

Comment: I used your solution with little `if` i.e `if(in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],['domain1.com','domain2.com'])){Debugbar::disable();}` Thank you very much.