# How to dynamically enable Laravel Debugbar?

Tags: laravel, debugging

How I can enable the Laravel Debugbar in runtime? I want to enable it based on a session variable. In my `AppServiceProvider` I add:

```
\Debugbar::enable()
```

But it is not working. If I set my `env` `APP_DEBUG` to `true` it works, so it's all fine with the debugbar (I've been using it successfully for a while now), but can't seem to turn it on/off in runtime? I'm on Laravel 5.4. I would like it off by default in my Production environment but with an option to turn it on as an admin/dev.

I did see this answer:
[Dynamically hide Laravel barryvdh debugbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47614322/dynamically-hide-laravel-barryvdh-debugbar)

However, I want it disabled by default and *enable* it when needed, rather than the opposite. That is because of performance, as per the debugbar's documentation:

> NB. Once enabled, the collectors are added (and could produce extra
>   overhead), so if you want to use the debugbar in production, disable
>   in the config and only enable when needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debug bar needs to capture everything that happens in your application, in order for this to happen, it must be running from before almost anything else happens in your application.

If you were to be able to turn it on for admins, for example, the application would need to fully boot, take your authentication assertion, check the database, and see you are an admin, and only then know that you want the debugger to be running.

The best thing you could do is spin up a second environment which has different ENV variables. You could even have it hitting the same production database if you wish, but it will need to be a separate App instance. In general this is a better workflow anyway, to have a staging environment which is identical to production. One small security consideration here is that any user with an account in your production instance, would also be able to log into this if its on the public web. So you'll want to protect it with either a password via .htaccess or maybe put an IP whitelist only for accessing the server so that its not just sitting out there. The debug has plenty of great information for people with bad intentions.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, however, I am not really in charge of the production server here, so there are definitely differences in local and production environments. The project also has its own small "ecosystem" with different services, sites etc. Often reproducing bugs in local is very tough, and I am trying to have enough tools to be able to find and trace bugs from production. Thanks for sharing your experience though, I will work on different approaches then :)

Comment: Since Debugbar has this functionality, it should work but it doesn't. For me also on Laravel 7. Please help anyone! :)

Comment: @Gediminas being a bit more experienced than I was when I first posted this, I can now say with more authority that you can't turn this on or off in runtime, because by the time Laravel can change the configs, it's too late for the Debug bar.  The best thing you could do is spin up a second environment which has different ENV variables. You could even have it hitting the same production database if you wish, but it will need to be a separate App instance. In general this is a good workflow anyway, to have a staging environment which is identical to production.

Comment: @cfkane please create an answer with *that* info, your current one is opinion based, the comments one is the fact based one :)

Comment: @raveren Fair ... hopefully that will be a bit more clear.